# How to net-ssh sudo su in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sudo, su, net-ssh

I'm trying to figure out how to a send chain of multiple net-ssh commands after a `sudo su - #{su_user}` in Ruby.

My current code is below, and hangs with the `sudo su` command, even after the `send_data "#{password}\n"`.

Meanwhile, on the system, a manual execution of `sudo su - admin2` does not require a password entry.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'net/ssh'
host = 'hostA'

user = 'admin'
password = 'hostA_pwd'
su_user = 'Admin2'

Net::SSH.start(host, user, :password => password) do |ssh|

     ssh.open_channel do |channel|  
       channel.request_pty do |c, success|
         raise "could not request pty" unless success

         channel.exec "pwd; whoami; sudo su - #{su_user} ; pwd ; whoami"
         channel.on_data do |c_, data|
           if data =~ /\[sudo\]/ || data =~ /Password/i
             channel.send_data "#{password}\n"
           else       
             result << data
           end
         end
         puts result
       end
     end
     ssh.loop
  end
```

Comment: You are aware that you can't chain commands like that after the `sudo` command? The last `pwd; whoami` won't be executed until after the sudo command shell returns. Did you take this into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo` supports the `-c` option, which passes a command to the sub-shell. Here are some of the `sudo` flags that might be useful to you:

```
-c, --command=COMMAND
      pass a single COMMAND to the shell with -c

--session-command=COMMAND
      pass a single COMMAND to the shell with -c and do not create a new session

-m, --preserve-environment
      do not reset environment variables

-s, --shell=SHELL
      run SHELL if /etc/shells allows it
```

So, using something like `sudo su someuser -c 'ls;date'`, you'll execute the commands `ls` and `date` as `someuser`. Give it a try at the command-line on that host to get a feel for what you can do, then apply it to your SSH session.

See `man sudo` for more information.

Also, just as a coding tip, you can reduce:

```
if data =~ /\[sudo\]/ || data =~ /Password/i
```

to:

```
if (data[/\[sudo\]|Password/i])
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,  I modified the line in code to include the -c option as Tin Man recommended. Thanks. <br /> channel.exec "pwd; whoami; sudo -u #{su_user} sh -c 'whoami ; cd /tmp ; pwd; ls'"

Comment: This was a great tip passing in -c 'command' under the sudo su someuser works well. That was a great tip.